# is it possible to initiate a Video call from Web application to Mobile app developed in xamarin?

Tags: web-applications, xamarin.forms, webrtc, tokbox, videochat

is it possible to initiate a Video call from Web application to Mobile app (developed in xamarin Form) based on customer ID (like notification should go to specific consumer of that app), if yes then where i may find some resources? Are there any plugins available for that?
Can i use tokbox or WebRTC for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

Yes, you can use the [OpenTok JS SDK](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/) along with the [Xamarin build](https://github.com/DreamTeamMobile/Xamarin.Opentok.Samples) maintained by one of our official partners, [Dream Team Mobile](https://dreamteam-mobile.com/).

You would have to implement the application logic where both the web and mobile users have to be in the same [session](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/basics/#sessions) to communicate with each other. For more information, please see our [documentation](https://tokbox.com/developer/).